# Che cosa significa "condannato in contumacia"?

Tags: meaning

Nelle note di Bianca Garavelli al canto XIX dell'*Inferno* di Dante Alighieri (edito da BUR) ho letto:

> Bonifacio VIII, cioè Benedetto Caetani, sarebbe morto nel 1303. Dante ha trovato però il modo di farlo venire all'Inferno anticipatamente: si è così almeno parzialmente vendicato del suo più terribile nemico, il responsabile principale del suo esilio. Infatti Dante nel 1301 andò da lui a Roma come ambasciatore di Firenze, ma nel frattempo   il papa congiurava con i Guelfi Neri fiorentini, decretando la sconfitta della parte bianca. Dante, perseguitato come tutti i Guelfi Bianchi, **condannato in contumacia** per baratteria, non sarebbe più tornato in patria.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "contumacia" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso di "condannato in contumacia" nel testo precedente. Vuol dire che Dante fu condannato senza essere presente nel giudizio? O il significato di "contumacia" in questo contesto corrisponderebbe all'accezione di segregazione o isolamento per un certo periodo di tempo e quindi farebbe riferimento alla condanna all'esilio di Dante?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il primo significato della voce [*contumacia* sul Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/contumacia) è quello che fa per te

> **1.** Nel diritto processuale penale, situazione di un imputato che, essendo stato citato in giudizio, si astiene dal comparire al dibattimento; […]

Nei tempi moderni questa astensione è spesso dovuta a latitanza. Alcuni ordinamenti giuridici non ammettono il processo in contumacia, quello italiano sì, o almeno [lo ammetteva](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contumacia#La_contumacia_nel_processo_penale:_il_nuovo_sistema_introdotto_nel_2014).

Dante fu appunto condannato in assenza; del resto ben sapeva quale sarebbe stato [l'esito del processo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante_Alighieri#L'inizio_dell'esilio_(1301-1304)):

> Alighieri Dante è condannato per baratteria, frode, falsità, dolo, malizia, inique pratiche estortive, proventi illeciti, pederastia, e lo si condanna a 5000 fiorini di multa, interdizione perpetua dai pubblici uffici, esilio perpetuo (in contumacia), e se lo si prende, al rogo, così che muoia.

Comment: Tuttavia, più che astenersi dal comparire, penso che in questo caso a Dante non era possibile essere presente.

Comment: @Charo Certo che avrebbe potuto essere presente, sarebbe bastato andare a Firenze. *Astenersi* significa “tenersi lontano*, come primo significato.

Answer (score 2):

Condannato in contumacia significa condannato senza essere mai stato presente al processo.

Nel caso di Dante egli era a Roma mentre a Firenze la sua parte politica veniva sconfitta, per cui verso tutti i suoi membri erano state mosse accuse che avevano portato ad un processo.

Dante nonostante non fosse presente al processo e non abbia potuto difendersi fu condannato in contumacia.

Gli effetti della condanna si hanno quando l’autorità giudiziaria può darne esecuzione arrestando il ricercato o latitante; nel caso Dante fosse tornato a Firenze sarebbe probabilmente stato arrestato.

Al giorno d’oggi esiste ancora questo tipo di condanna, specie nei confronti di latitanti della criminalità organizzata.